# How to make main menu item unclickable if it has a dropdown - TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am quite new to TypoScript, I am making a dropdown menu in TYPO3 which works perfectly fine.

When user clicks the menu item (with hamburger icon which indicates that this menu item has a dropdown) a dropdown opens up. I want to make the menu item itself not clickable, it should only open a dropdown menu. Below is my code, I would appreciate any ideas or help. Right Now, If I click the menu item item It opens up a new page (It should only open a dropdown).

```
lib.mobileNav = HMENU
lib.mobileNav {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    wrap =  <nav id="mobile-menu" class="main-nav"><ul> | </ul></nav>
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="1">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
              wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1">|</li>
              ATagTitle.field = title     
        }
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 dropdown">|</li>
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 active">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="level-1 active"
        }
        ACTIFSUB < .NO
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active level-1">|</li>

        }
    }
    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class=" level-2" role="menu">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-2">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="level-2"
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
        ACT = .NO
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active level-2">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="active level-2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've the parameter `doNotLinkIt` on the wrong level, it's for TMENU-items and not for the whole HMENU or whole TMENUs. You can see the reference [here in TSREF](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html)

Below is the menu as it should work, I sorted a bit to make it easier readable.

```
lib.mobileNav = HMENU
lib.mobileNav {

    entryLevel = 0
    wrap =  <nav id="mobile-menu" class="main-nav"><ul> | </ul></nav>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="1">|</ul>

        NO = 1
        NO {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1">|</li>
          ATagTitle.field = title
          doNotLinkIt = 1
        }

        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 dropdown">|</li>
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 active">|</li>
          ATagParams = class="level-1 active"
        }

        ACTIFSUB < .NO
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active level-1">|</li>
        }
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class=" level-2" role="menu">|</ul>

        NO = 1
        NO {
           doNotLinkIt = 1
           wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-2">|</li>
           ATagParams = class="level-2"
           stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active level-2">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="active level-2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can drop IFSUB = 1, ACT = 1 and ACTIFSUB = 1 because you copied them from NO = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the items without subitems should stay clickable or should be removed, since otherwise you will have menu entries that can not be clicked at all.

So the code for a menu with clickable items AND non-clickable items with dropdowns for subitems would look like this:

```
lib.mobileNav = HMENU
lib.mobileNav {

    entryLevel = 0
    wrap =  <nav id="mobile-menu" class="main-nav"><ul> | </ul></nav>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="1">|</ul>

        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1">|</li>
            ATagTitle.field = title
        }

        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 dropdown">|</li>
            doNotLinkIt = 1
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-1 active">|</li>
            ATagParams = class="level-1 active"
        }

        ACTIFSUB < .NO
        ACTIFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active level-1">|</li>
            doNotLinkIt = 1
        }
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class=" level-2" role="menu">|</ul>

    NO = 1
    NO {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li class="level-2">|</li>
       ATagParams = class="level-2"
       stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    }

    ACT < .NO
    ACT {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active level-2">|</li>
        ATagParams = class="active level-2"
    }
}
```

}